# Can't change div style with JS function

Tags: javascript, html, css

The main goal is to show different divs depending on which button I click, so they all start with the display style at "none" (except a default one called "atualizacoes"). And after I click a button ALL of the divs should be set to 
`display="none"` and after that the one I associated that button with is set to `display="block"`. 
However something isn't right because when I click one of the buttons, the default div does disappear however nothing ever appears.

This is how I'm trying to accomplishing it:

### In order:

> snippet 1 - function I use inside my index.html to change all the
>   displays
>
> snippet 2 - rule in my stylesheet
>
> snippet 3 - parts of my index.html code (I didn't want to paste
>   EVERYTHING)

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
   function replace(show) {
     document.getElementById('default').style.display="none";
     document.getElementById('ecra').style.display="none";
     document.getElementById(show).syle.display = "block";
   }
</script>
```

```css
.ecra
{
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="author" content="">
        <title>University Platform</title>
        <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
        <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
        <link href="dashboard.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <!-- jquery -->
        <script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      
  </head>
<body>

<!-- these are the buttons that are located on a sidebar -->
<div class="row">
  <h3>Options</h3>
  
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default botao pull-left" onclick="replace('addestudante')">Adicionar Estudante</button>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default botao pull-left" onclick="replace('adduc')">Adicionar UC</button>
</div>

<!-- these are the divs I want to switch around -->
<div class="row" id='default'>
           <p> Hello World </p>                     
</div>

<!-- in CSS I also made a rule that makes all "ecra" divs be invisible from the start-->
<div class="row ecra" id='addestudante'>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">  TEST 1</button>
</div>

<div class="row ecra" id='adduc'> 
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"> TEST 2</button>
</div>
  
  
</body>
```

Why is this function not working properly? Is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: There is no element with id `ecra`. Try using `document.getElementsByClassName` and using a for loop to apply the desired style to all of them.

Comment: Check the console for errors. There will be at least two of them ;)

Comment: I'm going to try the loop then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of issues with what you've written.

For one, you don't have any elements with ID "ecra" — what you want to do is affect all the elements that have the class "ecra". You can do this by looping or mapping over `document.getElementsByClassName("ecra")`.

Secondly, you've misspelt `style` when you try to show the `show` element.

Try using this adapted function instead:

```
function replace(show) {
    document.getElementById("default").style.display = "none";
    Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("ecra")).map(element => element.style.display = "none");
    document.getElementById(show).style.display = "block";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By what I thought, you want to get elements by class name. They're `ecra`, so you can use `querySelectorAll` and do a loop for its length. I'll not use `getElementsByClassName` because it will make the line more longer and return an array.

```
function replace(show){
    var q=document.querySelectorAll('.ecra'),
    document.getElementById('default').style.display="none";
    for(var i=0,l=q.length;i<l;i++){
            !function(i){
                    q[i].style.display="none"
            }(i)
    }
    document.querySelector('#'+show).style.display = "block"
}
```

Comment: There is no need for an IIFE in the loop.

Comment: @Andreas I put the "=0" ahead of itself now, but, well, my network's very slower to edit so fast. Not because in a day I got problems without doing this.

Answer (score 0):

I saw jQuery imported in your page. So I suggest to use jQuery.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function replace(show) {
          jQuery(function($){
                $("#default").css({
                    "display" : "none"
                });
                $(".ecra").css({
                    "display" : "none"
                });
                $("#"+show).css({
                    "display" : "block"
                });
          });
        }
</script>
```

Edited, missing characters.

Comment: doesn't seem to work, that does make it so that my divs appear, but it doesn't make every other div disappear

Comment: thanks @HugoSilva for your intervention huhuhuhuhu. I missed it hahahaha LOL

Comment: This one ALSO Works! Thanks guys :)

Answer (score 0):

JS corrected : http://jsfiddle.net/csfd8x35/

```css
.ecra
{
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<!-- these are the buttons that are located on a sidebar -->
<div class="row">
  <h3>Options</h3>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default botao pull-left" onclick="replace1('addestudante')">Adicionar Estudante</button>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default botao pull-left" onclick="replace1('adduc')">Adicionar UC</button>
</div>

<!-- these are the divs I want to switch around -->
<div class="row" id='default'>
           <p> Hello World </p>                     
</div>

<!-- in CSS I also made a rule that makes all "ecra" divs be invisible from the start-->
<div class="row ecra" id='addestudante'>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">  TEST 1</button>
</div>

<div class="row ecra" id='adduc'> 
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"> TEST 2</button>
</div>

<script>
    function replace1(show) {
     document.getElementById('default').style.display="none";
     var allByClass = document.getElementsByClassName('ecra');
                for (var i=0;i< allByClass.length; i++) {
                      allByClass[i].style.display = "none";
                }
     document.getElementById(show).style.display = "block";
   }
</script>
```